# RecyclerView cutting items off while scrolling back

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a problem with items inside Recycler View Adapter

When items are scrolled from left to right horizontally everything looks good.
But when when scrolling items back from right  positions to left ones the item with focus is cut off for at least half of a size.

I tried with changing width and height of recycler, as well as margins but it did not work

Recycler View Adapter

public class SettingsSceneCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
ArrayList<SettingsSceneCardItem> cardItems = new ArrayList<>();

private SettingsAdapterListener listener;
private OnSelectCallback onSelectCallback;

public SettingsSceneCardAdapter(SettingsAdapterListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public void setOnSelectCallback(OnSelectCallback callback) {
    this.onSelectCallback = callback;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_scene_settings_card_item, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    // Settings Scene Card Item cardItem
    final SettingsSceneCardItem cardItem = cardItems.get(position);

    // Card Item View
    holder.cardItemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#131B22"));

    // Card Item Text Description
    holder.cardItemDescription.setText(cardItem.getDescription());
    holder.cardItemDescription.setTextColorColor.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    holder.cardItemDescription.setTextSize(12);

    // Card Item Main Image Icon
    holder.cardItemMainImageIcon.setImageResource(cardItem.getMainIcon());
    holder.cardItemMainImageIcon.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
    holder.cardItemMainImageIcon.getLayoutParams().height = 100;

    // Focused Item View with shadow behinds the card item view
    holder.focusedItemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Set Card Item Focus Behaviour
    holder.cardItemView.setFocusable(true);
    holder.cardItemView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                if (onSelectCallback != null) {
                    onSelectCallback.onSelect(position);
                }

                holder.cardItemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                // Set Card Item Text Description Behaviour
                holder.cardItemDescription.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                holder.cardItemDescription.setTextSize(18);

                // Set Card Item Main Image Icon Behaviour
                holder.cardItemMainImageIcon.getLayoutParams().width = 120;
                holder.cardItemMainImageIcon.getLayoutParams().height = 120;

            } else {

                // Reset Card Item View Behaviour
               holder.cardItemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#131B22"));

                // Reset Card Item Text Description Behaviour
                holder.cardItemDescription.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                holder.cardItemDescription.setTextSize(12);

                // Reset Card Item Main Image Icon Behaviour
                holder.cardItemMainImageIcon.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
                holder.cardItemMainImageIcon.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
            }
        }
    });

    // TODO Add image listener
    holder.cardItemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("###################### CARD ITEM CLICKED POSITION " + position);
            listener.onItemClick(position);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cardItems.size();
}

/**
 * Recycler View Holder
 */
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    // Relative layout for focused card view item with shadow
    private RelativeLayout focusedItemView;

    // Relative layout for card item view
    private RelativeLayout cardItemView;

    //Image view main card item image icon
    private ImageView cardItemMainImageIcon;

    // Text view description
    private TextView cardItemDescription;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        focusedItemView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.settings_scene_card_item_view_focused);
        cardItemView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.settings_scene_card_item_view);
        cardItemMainImageIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.settings_scene_card_main_image_icon);
        cardItemDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.settings_scene_card_item_text_description);
    }
}


public interface SettingsAdapterListener {

    void onItemClick(int position);

    void onSelected(int position);
}



public interface OnSelectCallback {
    void onSelect(int index);
}

public void refreshCardItems(ArrayList<SettingsSceneCardItem> cardItems) {
    this.cardItems = cardItems;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}




<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/settings_scene_card_item_list_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/settings_scene_card_item_view_focused"
    android:layout_width="215dp"
    android:layout_height="328dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/settings_scene_card_item_view"
    android:layout_width="185.5dp"
    android:layout_height="278dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/settings_scene_card_main_image_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_scene_card_item_text_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_scene_card_main_image_icon"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using it with the SnapHelper?

Comment: No, I am using regular recycler view

Comment: You should use state selector instead of hardcoding view properties in java

Comment: Found any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use Snaphelper.This is for snapping the item in the center when scrolling in recyclerview.

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working. It only works when scrolling from left to right, but  not when I scroll back to left side

Comment: can post your xml also please?

Comment: only that much?the code of that arrow at the left also

Comment: Yes I just edited question with XML posts for Recycler and Item

Comment: Where is the code for that arrow in xml?I couldn’t find it

Comment: XML for the arrow is just a relative layout  with image view that goes in left container, and recycler goes in right container, I will post main layout with these two containers

Comment: ohk..post that xml also

Comment: So in the rl_sceneLeftContainer goes image view with arrow, and in rl_sceneRightContainer goes recycler, that has margin right -325 just for positioning. I tried to move thah but it doesnt affect the recycler

Comment: android:layout_marginRight="-325dp" statement is creating problem i guess..What I think is the imagview is overriding the recycler left side

Comment: I tried that as well, to remove right margin, and to put the left container to visibility Gone, but it won't work